# Place and/ or plane identification

Tags: aircraft

I am trying to identify both the place and the type of plane in this photograph. My father is inthe centre middle row (William Bone), who as far as I know stayed around Leeds during the war - I assumed that this photo was taken at Avro, Leeds but am not sure, and i haven't been able to track down any records for the factory there. However, i would be intereted to know what type of plane they are stood in front of. [image]

Answer (score 4):

The plane is a [Fairey Barracuda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairey_Barracuda), a torpedo/dive bomber of the Royal Navy. They were produced from 1941 to 1945.

Comment: I agree - the high wing placement is definitely more like the *Barracuda* than the *Battle*.

Comment: I think you're right - I missed the airbrake visible under the wing.

Comment: Many thanks ! Now just need to see if I can confirm these were maintained at the Avro factory in Yeadon, Leeds.

Comment: I can't find any source that Avro Leeds produced Fairey Barracudas. But Blackburn in Leeds did at least built major parts for the Fairey Barracuda.